# Requesting a [unity-ecs] tag, remove [ecs]=>[amazon-ecs] synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process, synonym-removal-request

The [ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecs) tag currently links to [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs). Unity's new ECS compoment system is currently in preview and will be stable at some point in the near future. As the ECS system is very different from the traditional Unity workflow, it makes sense to have a separate [unity-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ecs) tag and to remove the [ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecs)=>[amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs) synonym.

Comment: I would prefer that ecs doesn't exist either.